# Stopping a Python program when a def statement gives a specific result

Tags: python

I am trying to create a task based on the Dragon Realm game in the Invent your Own Games with Python book. The original allows one choice to be made and uses functions to set up those choices. I am trying to allow two separate choices to be made but can't figure out how to stop the task after the first choice if the def statement gives a specific result, ie. if the first choice is the wrong choice then the user does not get to make a second choice. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    #introduction

def chooseDoor():
    #user chooses door

def checkDoor(chosenDoor):
    #checks user choice against random number

    if chosenDoor == str(friendlyDoor):
        #various good stuff happens
    else:
        #bad stuff happens

    #at this point I would like to go back to the option to play again if they have chosen the wrong door
    #but I can't make it work by putting a break here as it goes on to the next def statement (chooseBox)
    #this is where the original game finished

def chooseBox():
#user chooses a box but only if they made the correct choice above

def checkBox(chosenBox):
#checks user choice against random number and good or bad stuff happens

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':

displayIntro()

doorNumber = chooseDoor()

checkDoor(doorNumber)

boxNumber = chooseBox()

checkBox(boxNumber)

#play again option
```

Comment: You should cut your code down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue. I can't tell which function call or selection you are referring to.

Comment: Think you could narrow this down a little? Ideally reduce your code to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but at the very least provide examples of the output you get compared to what you want.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I've posted ands wasn't sure what might be needed. Hopefully this shortened version is more appropriate? Thanks for your help.

Comment: and as tripleee pointed out below, I am actually looking to loop back to the option to play again and not completely stop the program, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The checkDoor() function should return a True if a friendly door is chosen, False if not. Then, in your main loop, modify

```
checkDoor()
```

to

```
if not checkDoor():
    continue
```

In this way, is the player chooses a non-friendly door, the function returns False, and the "continue" statement will reset the program to the next execution of the while loop. Otherwise, it goes on to chooseBox()

Comment: Where do you see `selection` in the question? What is `wrong`?

Comment: They are placeholders. You probably realize that, since you have a 9000 reputation. I thought the question was "how do i exit a program", not "what are my variables named".

Comment: Probably you should add some textual explanation for newbies, so they could understand why your code works. Link to documentation maybe. Btw, I have 3k rep, but don't judge me, I just got lucky.

Comment: The title is mialeading. In the question text, the OP actually asks how to exit back to (what amounts to) the main loop, not how to terminate the program.

Comment: Again, sorry, you are right. I want the user to be given the option to play again if they make the wrong choice initially.

Comment: Changed my -1 to +1. Given the specifics of this question, I don't think a better answer can be (succinctly) articulated.

Comment: Thanks blue_note that's great, much appreciated. I have added your suggestion and it has taken me back to the beginning. Is there anyway it can take me to the play again while loop?

Comment: Add another "#play again option" before the continue statement